# Why same code gets TLE in Python 3 but Accepted in Python 2

Tags: python, python-3.x

While solving [this problem in LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/3sum/description/), I submitted the following code in Python3 and got Time Limit Exceeded.

```
def threeSum(self, nums):
    """
    :type nums: List[int]
    :rtype: List[List[int]]
    """
    nums.sort()
    solutions = []
    for i in range(len(nums)-2):
        if i > 0 and nums[i] == nums[i - 1]:
            continue

        l = i + 1
        r = len(nums) - 1
        while l < r:
            if nums[i] + nums[l] + nums[r] == 0:
                solutions.append([nums[i], nums[l], nums[r]])
                while l < r and nums[l] == nums[l + 1]:
                    l += 1
                l += 1

                while l < r and nums[r] == nums[r - 1]:
                    r -= 1
                r -= 1
            elif nums[l] + nums[r] + nums[i] > 0:
                r -= 1
            else:
                l += 1

    return solutions
```

but when submitting the same solution in Python2, I got Accepted.

I am new to python and simply fail to understand why this is happening.

Comment: Certain things are slower in CPython 3 than CPython 2, and they tend to come up a lot in programming competitions. (IME CPython 3 takes about 30% longer.) If you have the option of running on PyPy3, do that – PyPy is about the same speed for 2 and 3, and *much* faster than CPython.

Comment: @Ryan Thanks, I don't see any option for using PyPy and also don't know anything about PyPy but I'm learning. I am newbie to this exiting world of Python.